# how to handle null while concatenate using || in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pandasql

I am concatenating the three column, but getting empty value , as one of three column is null sometime.
how to handle null column value while concatenating using || operator
code :
`>> select (t1.ab || t1.cd || t1.ef) as test from source`
output is empty when any one of them is null, otherwise it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 functions that you can use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) and [`IFNULL()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
select coalesce(t1.ab, '') || coalesce(t1.cd, '') || coalesce(t1.ef, '') as test 
from source
```

or:

```
select ifnull(t1.ab, '') || ifnull(t1.cd, '') || ifnull(t1.ef, '') as test 
from source
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any  function which wil take care of this null values like concat_ws() in mysql does.

Comment: No, SQLite does not support neither concat nor concat_ws().