# SQL Update Concatenate

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite db with a table named patients.
The table columns are fname, lname,mname and fullname.
The fullname column is blank.

I want to Update the column using the data from fname,lname and middle name.

I have tried the following SQL Statement:

```
    UPDATE patient
set fullname=lname+','+fname+','+mname;
```

but I get "0" in the fullname column.

What is the correct syntax to accomplish this task?

TIA

Comment: Are any of those 3 columns nullable and are there null values in any of the records? What about the total possible length of all 3 columns combined, does that exceed the schema length of `fullname`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013726/how-to-handle-null-while-concatenate-using-in-sqlite3) might be the solution for you.